# Using two threads to increase RFC1951 Deflate compression performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, compression

I have modified my implementation of RFC 1951 "Deflate" compression to use two threads. One thread performs the LZ77 matching, looking for sequences of at least three bytes that occur earlier in the input bytes, the other thread does the rest - compression with Huffman coding.

It works very well, giving a speed-up of about 30%. On the test I am running, it now out-performs ZLib, the standard implementation, obtaining superior compression without any speed penalty.

I am using a combination of Lock, Monitor.Wait, Monitor.Pulse and Thread.MemoryBarrier().

As I have not used C# threads before, I am slightly concerned whether I have got everything right, there are potential subtle issues where two threads are operating on shared data, so I'd be interested in reviews on that - is my threading code correct, could it be improved? [ Note: I do not use _ for private fields, please don't review that! ]

Here's the modified code:

```
using Generic = System.Collections.Generic;
using Monitor = System.Threading.Monitor;
using ThreadPool = System.Threading.ThreadPool;
using Thread = System.Threading.Thread;

#if x32
using uword = System.UInt32;
#else
using uword = System.UInt64;
#endif

namespace Pdf {


/* RFC 1951 compression ( https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1951.txt ) aims to compress a stream of bytes using :

   (1) LZ77 matching, where if an input sequences of at least 3 bytes re-occurs, it may be coded 
       as a <length,distance> pointer.

   (2) Huffman coding, where variable length codes are used, with more frequently used symbols encoded in less bits.

   The input may be split into blocks, a new block introduces a new set of Huffman codes. The choice of block 
   boundaries can affect compression. The method used to determine the block size is as follows:

   (1) The size of the next block to be output is set to an initial value.

   (2) A comparison is made between encoding two blocks of this size, or a double-length block.

   (3) If the double-length encoding is better, that becomes the block size, and the process repeats.

   LZ77 compression is implemented as suggested in the standard, although no attempt is made to
   truncate searches ( except searches terminate when the distance limit of 32k bytes is reached ).

   Only dynamic huffman blocks are used, no attempt is made to use Fixed or Copy blocks.

   A second thread is used to perform the LZ77 compression, to allow the Huffman coding and LZ77 
   comrpression to be done in parallel.

   Deflator ( this code) typically achieves better compression than ZLib 
   ( http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm  via https://zlib.net/ ) 
   and while compressing at a similar speed( default options, after warmup ).

   For example, compressing a font file FreeSans.ttf ( 264,072 bytes ), Zlib output 
   is 148,324 bytes in 19 milliseconds, whereas Deflator output is 143,666 bytes 
   in the same time.

   Sample usage:

   byte [] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
   var mbs = new MemoryBitStream();
   Deflator.Deflate( data, mbs );
   byte [] deflated_data = mbs.ToArray();

   The MemoryBitStream may alternatively be copied to a stream, this may be useful when writing PDF files ( the intended use case ).

   Auxiliary top level classes/structs ( included in this file ): 
   *  OutBitStream.
   *  MemoryBitStream : an implementation of OutBitStream.
   *  HuffmanCoding calculates Huffman codes.
   *  UlongHeap : used to implement HuffmanCoding.
*/   

sealed class Deflator 
{

  public static void Deflate( byte [] input, OutBitStream output )  // Deflate with default options.
  {
    Deflator d = new Deflator( input, output );
    d.Go();
  }

  // Options : to amend these use new Deflator( input, output ) and set before calling Go().
  // Possible "fast" setting : StartBlockSize = 0x4000, LazyMatch = false, DynamicBlockSize = false.
  public int StartBlockSize = 0x1000; // Increase to go faster ( with less compression ), reduce to try for more compression.
  public int MaxBufferSize = 0x8000; // Must be power of 2.

  // Compression options - set false to go faster, with less compression.
  public bool LZ77 = true;
  public bool LazyMatch = true;
  public bool DynamicBlockSize = true; 
  public bool TuneBlockSize = true;

  public bool RFC1950 = true; // Set false to suppress RFC 1950 fields.

  public Deflator( byte [] input, OutBitStream output )
  { 
    Input = input; 
    Output = output; 
  }

  public void Go()
  {
    if ( RFC1950 ) Output.WriteBits( 16, 0x9c78 );
    if ( LZ77 ) 
    {
      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( FindMatchesStart, this );
    } 
    else
    {
      Buffered = Input.Length;
    }
    while ( !OutputBlock() )
    {
      if ( LZ77 ) lock( this ) 
      { 
        if ( BufferFull ) Monitor.Pulse( this ); 
      }
    }
    if ( RFC1950 )
    { 
      Output.Pad( 8 );
      Output.WriteBits( 32, Adler32( Input ) );
    } 
  }

  // Private constants.

  // RFC 1951 match ( LZ77 ) limits.
  private const int MinMatch = 3; // The smallest match eligible for LZ77 encoding.
  private const int MaxMatch = 258; // The largest match eligible for LZ77 encoding.
  private const int MaxDistance = 0x8000; // The largest distance backwards in input from current position that can be encoded.

  // Instead of initialising LZ77 hashTable and link arrays to -(MaxDistance+1), EncodePosition 
  // is added when storing a value and subtracted when retrieving a value.
  // This means a default value of 0 will always be more distant than MaxDistance.
  private const int EncodePosition = MaxDistance + 1;

  // Private fields.

  private byte [] Input;
  private OutBitStream Output;

  private int Buffered; // How many Input bytes have been processed to intermediate buffer.
  private int Finished; // How many Input bytes have been written to Output.

  // Intermediate circular buffer for storing LZ77 matches.
  private int    [] PositionBuffer;
  private byte   [] LengthBuffer;
  private ushort [] DistanceBuffer;
  private int BufferMask;
  private int BufferWrite, BufferRead; // Indexes for writing and reading.

  // LZ77 hash table ( for MatchPossible function ).
  private int HashShift;
  private uint HashMask;
  private int [] HashTable;

  // Inter-thread signalling fields.
  private bool BufferFull = false;
  private bool InputWait = false;
  private int InputRequest;

  // Private functions and classes.

  private static int CalcBufferSize( int n, int max )
  // Calculates a power of 2 >= n, but not more than max.
  {
    if ( n >= max ) return max;
    int result = 1;
    while ( result < n ) result = result << 1;
    return result;
  }

  private void FindMatches() // LZ77 compression.
  {
    byte [] input = Input;
    if ( input.Length < MinMatch ) return;

    int bufferSize = CalcBufferSize( input.Length / 3, MaxBufferSize );
    PositionBuffer = new int[ bufferSize ];
    LengthBuffer   = new byte[ bufferSize ];
    DistanceBuffer = new ushort[ bufferSize ];   
    BufferMask = bufferSize - 1; 

    int limit = input.Length - 2;

    int hashShift = CalcHashShift( limit * 2 );
    uint hashMask = ( 1u << ( MinMatch * hashShift ) ) - 1;

    int [] hashTable = new int[ hashMask + 1 ];
    int [] link = new int[ limit ];

    HashShift = hashShift;
    HashMask = hashMask;
    HashTable = hashTable;

    int position = 0; // position in input.

    // hash will be hash of three bytes starting at position.
    uint hash = ( (uint)input[ 0 ] << hashShift ) + input[ 1 ];

    while ( position < limit )
    {
      hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;        
      int hashEntry = hashTable[ hash ];
      hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
      if ( position >= hashEntry ) // Equivalent to position - ( hashEntry - EncodePosition ) > MaxDistance.
      {
         position += 1;
         continue;
      }
      link[ position ] = hashEntry;

      int distance, match = BestMatch( input, position, out distance, hashEntry - EncodePosition, link );
      position += 1;
      if ( match < MinMatch ) continue;

      // "Lazy matching" RFC 1951 p.15 : if there are overlapping matches, there is a choice over which of the match to use.
      // Example: "abc012bc345.... abc345". Here abc345 can be encoded as either [abc][345] or as a[bc345].
      // Since a range typically needs more bits to encode than a single literal, choose the latter.
      while ( LazyMatch && position < limit ) 
      {
        hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;          
        hashEntry = hashTable[ hash ];
        hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
        if ( position >= hashEntry ) break;
        link[ position ] = hashEntry;

        int distance2, match2 = BestMatch( input, position, out distance2, hashEntry - EncodePosition, link );
        if ( match2 > match || match2 == match && distance2 < distance )
        {
          match = match2;
          distance = distance2;
          position += 1;
        }
        else break;
      }

      int copyEnd = SaveMatch( position - 1, match, distance );
      if ( copyEnd > limit ) copyEnd = limit;

      position += 1;

      // Advance to end of copied section.
      while ( position < copyEnd )
      { 
        hash = ( ( hash << hashShift ) + input[ position + 2 ] ) & hashMask;
        link[ position ] = hashTable[ hash ];
        hashTable[ hash ] = position + EncodePosition;
        position += 1;
      }
    }

    HashTable = null; // To potentially free up memory.

    lock( this )
    {
      Buffered = Input.Length;
      if ( InputWait ) Monitor.Pulse( this );
    } 

  }

  // BestMatch finds the best match starting at position. 
  // oldPosition is from hash table, link [] is linked list of older positions.

  private int BestMatch( byte [] input, int position, out int bestDistance, int oldPosition, int [] link )
  { 
    int avail = input.Length - position;
    if ( avail > MaxMatch ) avail = MaxMatch;

    int bestMatch = 0; bestDistance = 0;
    byte keyByte = input[ position + bestMatch ];

    while ( true )
    { 
      if ( input[ oldPosition + bestMatch ] == keyByte )
      {
        int match = 0; 
        while ( match < avail && input[ position + match ] == input[ oldPosition + match ] ) 
        {
          match += 1;
        }
        if ( match > bestMatch )
        {
          bestMatch = match;
          bestDistance = position - oldPosition;
          if ( bestMatch == avail || ! MatchPossible( position, bestMatch + 1 ) ) break;
          keyByte = input[ position + bestMatch ];
        }
      }
      oldPosition = link[ oldPosition ];
      if ( position >= oldPosition ) break;
      oldPosition -= EncodePosition;
    }
    return bestMatch;
  }

  // MatchPossible is used to try and shorten the BestMatch search by checking whether 
  // there is a hash entry for the last 3 bytes of the next longest possible match.

  private bool MatchPossible( int position, int matchLength )
  {
    int end = position + matchLength - 3;
    uint hash = ( (uint)Input[ end + 0 ] << HashShift ) + Input[ end + 1 ];
    hash = ( ( hash << HashShift ) + Input[ end + 2 ] ) & HashMask;        
    int hashEntry = HashTable[ hash ];
    return end < hashEntry;
  }

  private static int CalcHashShift( int n )
  {
    int p = 1;
    int result = 0;
    while ( n > p ) 
    {
      p = p << MinMatch;
      result += 1;
      if ( result == 6 ) break;
    }
    return result;
  } 

  private static void FindMatchesStart( System.Object x )
  {
    Deflator d = (Deflator) x;
    d.FindMatches();
  }

  private int SaveMatch ( int position, int length, int distance )
  // Called from FindMatches to save a <length,distance> match. Returns position + length.
  {
    int i = BufferWrite;
    PositionBuffer[ i ] = position;
    LengthBuffer[ i ] = (byte) (length - MinMatch);
    DistanceBuffer[ i ] = (ushort) distance;
    i = ( i + 1 ) & BufferMask;

    while ( i == BufferRead )
    lock ( this )
    {
      BufferFull = true;
      if ( InputWait ) Monitor.Pulse( this );
      Monitor.Wait( this );
      BufferFull = false;
    }

    Thread.MemoryBarrier();
    BufferWrite = i;
    position += length;
    Buffered = position;

    if ( InputWait && position >= InputRequest )
      lock ( this ) Monitor.Pulse( this );

    return position;
  }

  private int WaitForInput( int request )
  {
    while ( true ) 
    lock( this )
    {
      if ( Buffered == Input.Length || BufferFull || Buffered >= request ) 
        return Buffered;
      else
      {
        InputRequest = request;
        InputWait = true;
        Monitor.Wait( this );
        InputWait = false;
      }
    }
  }

  private bool OutputBlock()
  {
    int blockSize = WaitForInput( Finished + StartBlockSize ) - Finished;

    if ( blockSize > StartBlockSize ) 
    {
      blockSize = ( Buffered == Input.Length && blockSize < StartBlockSize * 2 ) ? blockSize >> 1 : StartBlockSize;
    }

    Block b = new Block( this, blockSize, null );
    int bits = b.GetBits(); // Compressed size in bits.
    int tunedBlockSize = blockSize;

    // Investigate larger block size.
    while ( DynamicBlockSize ) 
    {
      int avail = WaitForInput( b.End + blockSize );

      if ( b.End + blockSize > avail ) break;

      // b2 is a block which starts just after b.
      Block b2 = new Block( this, blockSize, b );

      // b3 covers b and b2 exactly as one block.
      Block b3 = new Block( this, b2.End - b.Start, null );

      int bits2 = b2.GetBits();
      int bits3 = b3.GetBits(); 

      int delta = TuneBlockSize ? b2.TuneBoundary( this, b, blockSize / 4, out tunedBlockSize ) : 0;

      if ( bits3 > bits + bits2 + delta ) break;

      bits = bits3;
      b = b3;
      blockSize += blockSize; 
      tunedBlockSize = blockSize;
    }      

    if ( tunedBlockSize > blockSize )
    {
      b = new Block( this, tunedBlockSize, null ); 
      b.GetBits();
    }

    bool last = b.End == Input.Length;

    b.WriteBlock( this, last );  

    return last;
  }

  public static uint Adler32( byte [] b ) // Checksum function per RFC 1950.
  {
    uint s1 = 1, s2 = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < b.Length; i += 1 )
    {
      s1 = ( s1 + b[ i ] ) % 65521;
      s2 = ( s2 + s1 ) % 65521;
    }
    return s2 * 65536 + s1;    
  }

  private class Block
  {
    public readonly int Start, End; // Range of input encoded.

    public Block( Deflator d, int blockSize, Block previous )
    // The block is not immediately output, to allow caller to try different block sizes.
    // Instead, the number of bits neeed to encoded the block is returned by GetBits ( excluding "extra" bits ).
    {
      Output = d.Output;

      if ( previous == null )
      {
        Start = d.Finished;
        BufferStart = d.BufferRead;
      }
      else
      {
        Start = previous.End;
        BufferStart = previous.BufferEnd;
      }

      int avail = d.Buffered - Start;
      if ( blockSize > avail ) blockSize = avail;

      End = TallyFrequencies( d, blockSize );
      Lit.Used[ 256 ] += 1; // End of block code.
    }

    public int GetBits()
    {
      Lit.ComputeCodes();
      Dist.ComputeCodes();

      if ( Dist.Count == 0 ) Dist.Count = 1;

      // Compute length encoding.
      DoLengthPass( 1 );
      Len.ComputeCodes();

      // The length codes are permuted before being stored ( so that # of trailing zeroes is likely to be more ).
      Len.Count = 19; while ( Len.Count > 4 && Len.Bits[ ClenAlphabet[ Len.Count - 1 ] ] == 0 ) Len.Count -= 1;

      return 17 + 3 * Len.Count + Len.Total() + Lit.Total() + Dist.Total();
    }

    public void WriteBlock( Deflator d, bool last )
    {
      OutBitStream output = Output;
      output.WriteBits( 1, last ? 1u : 0u );
      output.WriteBits( 2, 2 );
      output.WriteBits( 5, (uint)( Lit.Count - 257 ) ); 
      output.WriteBits( 5, (uint)( Dist.Count - 1 ) ); 
      output.WriteBits( 4, (uint)( Len.Count - 4 ) );

      for ( int i = 0; i < Len.Count; i += 1 ) 
        output.WriteBits( 3, Len.Bits[ ClenAlphabet[ i ] ] );

      DoLengthPass( 2 );
      PutCodes( d );
      output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ 256 ], Lit.Codes[ 256 ] ); // End of block code
    }

    // Block private fields and constants.

    private OutBitStream Output;
    private int BufferStart, BufferEnd;

    // Huffman codings : Lit = Literal or Match Code, Dist = Distance code, Len = Length code.
    HuffmanCoding Lit = new HuffmanCoding(15,288), Dist = new HuffmanCoding(15,32), Len = new HuffmanCoding(7,19);

    // Counts for code length encoding.
    private int LengthPass, PreviousLength, ZeroRun, Repeat;

    // RFC 1951 constants.
    private readonly static byte [] ClenAlphabet = { 16, 17, 18, 0, 8, 7, 9, 6, 10, 5, 11, 4, 12, 3, 13, 2, 14, 1, 15 };
    private readonly static byte [] MatchExtra = { 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4, 5,5,5,5, 0 };
    private readonly static ushort [] MatchOff = { 3,4,5,6, 7,8,9,10, 11,13,15,17, 19,23,27,31, 35,43,51,59, 
      67,83,99,115,  131,163,195,227, 258, 0xffff };
    private readonly static byte [] DistExtra = { 0,0,0,0, 1,1,2,2, 3,3,4,4, 5,5,6,6, 7,7,8,8, 9,9,10,10, 11,11,12,12, 13,13 };
    private readonly static ushort [] DistOff = { 1,2,3,4, 5,7,9,13, 17,25,33,49, 65,97,129,193, 257,385,513,769, 
      1025,1537,2049,3073, 4097,6145,8193,12289, 16385,24577 };

    // Block private functions.

    private int TallyFrequencies( Deflator d, int blockSize )
    {
      int position = Start;
      int end = position + blockSize;

      int bufferRead = BufferStart;
      while ( position < end && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        if ( matchPosition >= end ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ] + MinMatch;
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead ];
        bufferRead = ( bufferRead + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        byte [] input = d.Input;
        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          Lit.Used[ input[ position ] ] += 1;
          position += 1;
        }

        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        Lit.Used[ 257 + mc ] += 1;
        Dist.Used[ dc ] += 1;     
      }

      while ( position < end ) 
      {
        Lit.Used[ d.Input[ position ] ] += 1;
        position += 1;
      }

      BufferEnd = bufferRead;
      return position;
    }

    public int TuneBoundary( Deflator d, Block prev, int howfar, out int blockSize )
    {
      // Investigate whether moving data into the previous block uses fewer bits,
      // using the current encodings. If a symbol with no encoding in the 
      // previous block is found, terminate the search ( goto EndSearch ).

      int position = Start;
      int bufferRead = BufferStart;
      int end = position + howfar;
      if ( end > End ) end = End;

      int delta = 0, bestDelta = 0, bestPosition = position;

      while ( position < end && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];

        if ( matchPosition >= end ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ] + MinMatch;
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead  ]; 

        bufferRead = ( bufferRead  + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          byte b = d.Input[ position ];

          if ( prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] == 0 ) goto EndSearch;
          delta += prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] - Lit.Bits[ b ];
          if ( delta < bestDelta ) { bestDelta = delta; bestPosition = position; }
          position += 1;
        }  
        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        if ( prev.Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ] == 0 || prev.Dist.Bits[ dc ] == 0 ) goto EndSearch;
        delta += prev.Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ] - Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc  ];
        delta += prev.Dist.Bits[ dc ] - Dist.Bits[ dc ];

        if ( delta < bestDelta ) { bestDelta = delta; bestPosition = position; }
        position += 1;
      }

      while ( position < end ) 
      {
        byte b = d.Input[ position ];
        if ( prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] == 0 ) goto EndSearch;
        delta += prev.Lit.Bits[ b ] - Lit.Bits[ b ];
        if ( delta < bestDelta ) { bestDelta = delta; bestPosition = position; }
        position += 1;
      }  

      EndSearch:

      blockSize = bestPosition - prev.Start;
      return bestDelta;
    }

    private void PutCodes( Deflator d )
    {
      byte [] input = d.Input;
      OutBitStream output = d.Output;

      int position = Start;
      int bufferRead = BufferStart;

      while ( position < End && bufferRead != d.BufferWrite )
      {
        int matchPosition = d.PositionBuffer[ bufferRead ];

        if ( matchPosition >= End ) break;

        int length = d.LengthBuffer[ bufferRead ] + MinMatch;
        int distance = d.DistanceBuffer[ bufferRead  ]; 

        bufferRead = ( bufferRead  + 1 ) & d.BufferMask;

        while ( position < matchPosition ) 
        {
          byte b = d.Input[ position ];
          output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ b ], Lit.Codes[ b ] );
          position += 1;
        }  
        position += length;

        // Compute match and distance codes.
        int mc = 0; while ( length >= MatchOff[ mc ] ) mc += 1; mc -= 1;
        int dc = 29; while ( distance < DistOff[ dc ] ) dc -= 1;

        output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ 257 + mc ], Lit.Codes[ 257 + mc ] );
        output.WriteBits( MatchExtra[ mc ], (uint)(length-MatchOff[ mc ] ) );
        output.WriteBits( Dist.Bits[ dc ], Dist.Codes[ dc ] );
        output.WriteBits( DistExtra[ dc ], (uint)(distance-DistOff[ dc ] ) );    
      }

      while ( position < End ) 
      {
        byte b = input[ position ];
        output.WriteBits( Lit.Bits[ b ], Lit.Codes[ b ] );
        position += 1;
      }  

      Thread.MemoryBarrier();

      d.BufferRead = bufferRead;
      d.Finished = position;
    }

    // Run length encoding of code lengths - RFC 1951, page 13.

    private void DoLengthPass( int pass )
    {
      LengthPass = pass; 
      EncodeLengths( Lit.Count, Lit.Bits, true );     
      EncodeLengths( Dist.Count, Dist.Bits, false );
    }

    private void PutLength( int code ) 
    { 
      if ( LengthPass == 1 ) 
        Len.Used[ code ] += 1; 
      else 
        Output.WriteBits( Len.Bits[ code ], Len.Codes[ code ] ); 
    }

    private void EncodeLengths( int n, byte [] lengths, bool isLit )
    {
      if ( isLit ) 
      { 
        PreviousLength = 0; 
        ZeroRun = 0; 
        Repeat = 0; 
      }
      for ( int i = 0; i < n; i += 1 )
      {
        int length = lengths[ i ];
        if ( length == 0 )
        { 
          if ( Repeat > 0 ) EncodeRepeat(); 
          ZeroRun += 1; 
          PreviousLength = 0; 
        }
        else if ( length == PreviousLength ) 
        {
          Repeat += 1;
        }
        else 
        { 
          if ( ZeroRun > 0 ) EncodeZeroRun(); 
          if ( Repeat > 0 ) EncodeRepeat(); 
          PutLength( length );
          PreviousLength = length; 
        }
      }      
      if ( !isLit ) 
      { 
        EncodeZeroRun(); 
        EncodeRepeat();
      }
    }

    private void EncodeRepeat()
    {
      while ( Repeat > 0 )
      {
        if ( Repeat < 3 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( PreviousLength ); 
          Repeat -= 1; 
        }
        else 
        { 
          int x = Repeat; 
          if ( x > 6 ) x = 6; 
          PutLength( 16 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 )
          { 
            Output.WriteBits( 2, (uint)( x - 3 ) ); 
          }
          Repeat -= x;  
        }
      }
    }

    private void EncodeZeroRun()
    {
      while ( ZeroRun > 0 )
      {
        if ( ZeroRun < 3 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( 0 ); 
          ZeroRun -= 1; 
        }
        else if ( ZeroRun < 11 ) 
        { 
          PutLength( 17 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 ) Output.WriteBits( 3, (uint)( ZeroRun - 3 ) ); 
          ZeroRun = 0;  
        }
        else 
        { 
          int x = ZeroRun; 
          if ( x > 138 ) x = 138; 
          PutLength( 18 ); 
          if ( LengthPass == 2 ) Output.WriteBits( 7, (uint)( x - 11 ) ); 
          ZeroRun -= x; 
        }
      }
    }
  } // end class Block

} // end class Deflator


// ******************************************************************************


struct HuffmanCoding // Variable length coding.
{
  public ushort Count; // Number of symbols.
  public byte [] Bits; // Number of bits used to encode a symbol ( code length ).
  public ushort [] Codes; // Huffman code for a symbol ( bit 0 is most significant ).
  public int [] Used; // Count of how many times a symbol is used in the block being encoded.

  private int Limit; // Limit on code length ( 15 or 7 for RFC 1951 ).
  private ushort [] Left, Right; // Tree storage.

  public HuffmanCoding( int limit, ushort symbols )
  {
    Limit = limit;
    Count = symbols;
    Bits = new byte[ symbols ];
    Codes = new ushort[ symbols ];
    Used = new int[ symbols ];
    Left = new ushort[ symbols ];
    Right = new ushort[ symbols ];
  }

  public int Total()
  {
    int result = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
      result += Used[i] * Bits[i];
    return result;
  }

  public void ComputeCodes() // Compute Bits and Codes from Used.
  {
    // Tree nodes are encoded in a ulong using 16 bits for the id, 8 bits for the tree depth, 32 bits for Used.
    const int IdBits = 16, DepthBits = 8, UsedBits = 32;
    const uint IdMask = ( 1u << IdBits ) - 1;
    const uint DepthOne = 1u << IdBits;
    const uint DepthMask = ( ( 1u << DepthBits ) - 1 ) << IdBits;
    const ulong UsedMask = ( ( 1ul << UsedBits ) - 1 ) << ( IdBits + DepthBits );

    // First compute the number of bits to encode each symbol (Bits).
    UlongHeap heap = new UlongHeap( Count );

    for ( ushort i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 )
    {
      int used = Used[ i ];
      if ( used > 0 )
        heap.Add( (ulong)used << ( IdBits + DepthBits ) | i );
    }
    heap.Make();

    int nonZero = heap.Count;
    int maxBits = 0;

    if ( heap.Count == 1 )
    { 
      GetBits( unchecked( (ushort) heap.Remove() ), 1 );
      maxBits = 1;
    }
    else if ( heap.Count > 1 ) unchecked
    {
      ulong treeNode = Count;

      do // Keep pairing the lowest frequency TreeNodes.
      {
        ulong left = heap.Remove(); 
        Left[ treeNode - Count ] = (ushort) left;

        ulong right = heap.Remove(); 
        Right[ treeNode - Count ] = (ushort) right;

        // Extract depth of left and right nodes ( still shifted though ).
        uint depthLeft = (uint)left & DepthMask, depthRight = (uint)right & DepthMask; 

        // New node depth is 1 + larger of depthLeft and depthRight.
        uint depth = ( depthLeft > depthRight ? depthLeft : depthRight ) + DepthOne;

        heap.Insert( ( left + right ) & UsedMask | depth | treeNode );

        treeNode += 1;
      }  while ( heap.Count > 1 );

      uint root = (uint) heap.Remove() & ( DepthMask | IdMask );
      maxBits = (int)( root >> IdBits );
      if ( maxBits <= Limit )
        GetBits( (ushort)root, 0 );
      else
      {
        maxBits = Limit;
        PackageMerge( nonZero );
      }
    }

    // Computation of code lengths (Bits) is complete.
    // Now compute Codes, code below is from RFC 1951 page 7.

    int [] bl_count = new int[ maxBits + 1 ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
      bl_count[ Bits[ i ] ] += 1; 

    int [] next_code = new int[ maxBits + 1 ];
    int code = 0; bl_count[ 0 ] = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < maxBits; i += 1 ) 
    {
      code = ( code + bl_count[ i ] ) << 1;
      next_code[ i + 1 ] = code;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
    {
      int length = Bits[ i ];
      if ( length != 0 ) 
      {
        Codes[ i ] = (ushort) Reverse( next_code[ length ], length );
        next_code[ length ] += 1;
      }
    }

    // Reduce Count if there are unused trailing symbols.
    while ( Count > 0 && Bits[ Count - 1 ] == 0 ) Count -= 1;

  }

  private void GetBits( ushort treeNode, int length )
  {
    if ( treeNode < Count ) // treeNode is a leaf.
    {
      Bits[ treeNode ] = (byte)length;
    }
    else 
    {
      treeNode -= Count;
      length += 1;
      GetBits( Left[ treeNode ], length );
      GetBits( Right[ treeNode ], length );
    }
  }

  private static int Reverse( int x, int bits )
  // Reverse a string of bits ( ready to be output as Huffman code ).
  { 
    int result = 0; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < bits; i += 1 ) 
    {
      result <<= 1; 
      result |= x & 1; 
      x >>= 1; 
    } 
    return result; 
  } 

  // PackageMerge is used if the Limit is exceeded.
  // The result is technically not a Huffman code in this case.
  // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package-merge_algorithm for a description of the algorithm.

  private void PackageMerge( int usedNonZero )
  {
    // Tree nodes are encoded in a ulong using 16 bits for the id, 32 bits for Used.
    const int IdBits = 16, UsedBits = 32;
    const ulong UsedMask = ( ( 1ul << UsedBits ) - 1 ) << IdBits;

    Left = new ushort[ Count * Limit ];
    Right = new ushort[ Count * Limit ];

    // First create the leaf nodes and sort.

    ulong [] sorted = new ulong[ usedNonZero ];
    for ( uint i = 0, j = 0; i < Count; i += 1 ) 
    {
      if ( Used[ i ] != 0 ) 
      {
        sorted[ j++ ] = (ulong)Used[ i ] << IdBits | i;
      }
    }
    System.Array.Sort( sorted );

    // Sort is complete.

    // List class is from System.Collections.Generic.
    Generic.List<ulong> merged = new Generic.List<ulong>( Count ), 
                next = new Generic.List<ulong>( Count );

    uint package = (uint) Count; // Allocator for package ids.

    for ( int i = 0; i < Limit; i += 1 ) 
    {
      int j = 0, k = 0; // Indexes into the lists being merged.
      next.Clear();
      for ( int total = ( sorted.Length + merged.Count ) / 2; total > 0; total -= 1 )  
      {
        ulong left, right; // The tree nodes to be packaged.

        if ( k < merged.Count )
        {
          left = merged[ k ];
          if ( j < sorted.Length )
          {
            ulong sj = sorted[ j ];
            if ( left < sj ) k += 1;
            else { left = sj; j += 1; }
          }
          else k += 1;
        }
        else left = sorted[ j++ ];

        if ( k < merged.Count )
        {
          right = merged[ k ];
          if ( j < sorted.Length )
          {
            ulong sj = sorted[ j ];
            if ( right < sj ) k += 1;
            else { right = sj; j += 1; }
          }
          else k += 1;
        }
        else right = sorted[ j++ ];

        Left[ package ] = unchecked( (ushort) left );
        Right[ package ] = unchecked( (ushort) right );
        next.Add( ( left + right ) & UsedMask | package );        
        package += 1;
      }

      // Swap merged and next.
      Generic.List<ulong> tmp = merged; merged = next; next = tmp;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < merged.Count; i += 1 )
      MergeGetBits( unchecked( (ushort) merged[i] ) );
  }

  private void MergeGetBits( ushort node )
  {
    if ( node < Count )
      Bits[ node ] += 1;
    else
    {
      MergeGetBits( Left[ node ] );
      MergeGetBits( Right[ node ] );
    }
  }

} // end struct HuffmanCoding


// ******************************************************************************


struct UlongHeap // An array organised so the smallest element can be efficiently removed.
{
  public int Count { get{ return _Count; } }
  private int _Count;
  private ulong [] Array;

  public UlongHeap ( int capacity )
  {
    _Count = 0;
    Array = new ulong[ capacity ];
  }

  public void Insert( ulong e )
  {
    int j = _Count++;
    while ( j > 0 )
    {
      int p = ( j - 1 ) >> 1; // Index of parent.
      ulong pe = Array[ p ];
      if ( e >= pe ) break;
      Array[ j ] = pe; // Demote parent.
      j = p;
    }    
    Array[ j ] = e;
  }

  public ulong Remove() // Returns the smallest element.
  {
    ulong result = Array[ 0 ];
    _Count -= 1;
    ulong e = Array[ _Count ];
    int j = 0;
    while ( true )
    {
      int c = j + j + 1; if ( c >= _Count ) break;
      ulong ce = Array[ c ];
      if ( c + 1 < _Count )
      {
        ulong ce2 = Array[ c + 1 ];
        if ( ce2 < ce ) { c += 1; ce = ce2; }
      } 
      if ( ce >= e ) break;
      Array[ j ] = ce; j = c;  
    }
    Array[ j ] = e;
    return result;
  }

  // Add and Make allow the heap to be initialised faster ( in theory at least ).

  public void Add( ulong e )
  {
    Array[ _Count++ ] = e;
  }

  /* Diagram showing numbering of tree elements.
           0
       1       2
     3   4   5   6
  */

  public void Make()
  {
    // Initialise the heap by making every parent less than both it's children.
    int p = ( _Count - 2 ) / 2; // parent of last element.
    while ( p >= 0 )
    {
      // Bubble element at p down.
      int j = p;
      ulong e = Array[ j ];
      while ( true )
      {
        int c = j + j + 1; if ( c >= _Count ) break;
        ulong ce = Array[ c ];
        if ( c + 1 < _Count )
        {
          ulong ce2 = Array[ c + 1 ];
          if ( ce2 < ce ) { c += 1; ce = ce2; }
        }
        if ( ce >= e ) break;
        Array[ j ] = ce; j = c;
      }
      Array[ j ] = e;
      p -= 1;   
    }
  }

} // end struct UlongHeap


// ******************************************************************************


abstract class OutBitStream
{
  public void WriteBits( int n, uword value )
  // Write first n bits of value to stream, least significant bit is written first.
  // Unused bits of value must be zero, i.e. value must be in range 0 .. 2^n-1.
  {
    if ( n + BitsInWord >= WordCapacity )
    {
      Save( value << BitsInWord | Word );
      int space = WordCapacity - BitsInWord;
      value >>= space;
      n -= space;
      Word = 0;
      BitsInWord = 0;
    }
    Word |= value << BitsInWord;
    BitsInWord += n;
  }

  public void Pad( int n )
  // Pad with zero bits to n bit boundary where n is power of 2 in range 1,2,4..64, typically n=8.
  {
    int w = BitsInWord % n; 
    if ( w > 0 ) WriteBits( n - w, 0 );
  }

  public abstract void Save( uword word );

  protected const int WordCapacity = sizeof(uword) * 8; // Number of bits that can be stored in Word
  protected uword Word; // Bits are first stored in Word, when full, Word is saved.
  protected int BitsInWord; // Number of bits currently stored in Word.

}


// ******************************************************************************


class MemoryBitStream : OutBitStream
{
  // An implementation of OutBitStream where the bits are stored in memory.
  // The storage is a linked list of Chunks.
  // ByteSize returns the current size in bytes.
  // CopyTo copies the contents to a Stream.
  // ToArray returns the contents as an array of bytes.

  public int ByteSize() 
  {
    return CompleteChunks * Chunk.Capacity + BytesInCurrentChunk + ( BitsInWord + 7 ) / 8;
  }

  public void CopyTo( System.IO.Stream s ) 
  {
    for ( Chunk c = FirstChunk; c != null; c = c.Next )
    { 
      int n = ( c == CurrentChunk ) ? BytesInCurrentChunk : Chunk.Capacity;
      s.Write( c.Bytes, 0, n ); 
    }

    int biw = BitsInWord;
    uword word = Word;
    while ( biw > 0 )
    {
      s.WriteByte( unchecked( (byte) word ) );
      word >>= 8;
      biw -= 8;
    }
  }

  public byte [] ToArray()
  {
    byte [] result = new byte[ ByteSize() ];
    int i = 0;

    for ( Chunk c = FirstChunk; c != null; c = c.Next )
    { 
      int n = ( c == CurrentChunk ) ? BytesInCurrentChunk : Chunk.Capacity;
      System.Array.Copy( c.Bytes, 0, result, i, n ); 
      i += n;
    }

    int biw = BitsInWord;
    uword word = Word;
    while ( biw > 0 )
    {
      result[ i++ ] = unchecked( (byte) word );
      word >>= 8;
      biw -= 8;
    }
    return result;
  }

  public MemoryBitStream()
  {
    FirstChunk = new Chunk();
    CurrentChunk = FirstChunk;
  }

  public override void Save( uword w )
  {
    if ( BytesInCurrentChunk == Chunk.Capacity )
    {
      Chunk nc = new Chunk();
      CurrentChunk.Next = nc;
      CurrentChunk = nc;
      CompleteChunks += 1;
      BytesInCurrentChunk = 0;
    }
    int i = BytesInCurrentChunk;
    byte [] bytes = CurrentChunk.Bytes;
    unchecked
    {
      #if x32
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w;
      #else
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w; w >>= 8;
      bytes[ i++ ] = (byte) w;
      #endif
    }
    BytesInCurrentChunk = i;
  }

  protected class Chunk
  {
    public const int Capacity = 0x800;
    public byte [] Bytes = new byte[ Capacity ];
    public Chunk Next;
  }

  protected int BytesInCurrentChunk;
  protected int CompleteChunks;
  protected Chunk FirstChunk, CurrentChunk;

} // end class MemoryBitStream


} // end namespace Pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing too exciting to say, but having spent some time looking through the code, thought I might as well post something:

## Code Separation

I'd be compelled to separate the LZ77 FindMatches logic from the other logic; I would want as little interface between these as possible (e.g. `HashTable` should not be available to the other thread).

I'd also want to pull all of the communication between the 2 threads into a separate component, so that this logical interface is as clear as possible. As someone looking at your code for the first time, this logical interface is difficult to discern (without tooling), and that makes it very hard to try to verify the threading code.

## Threading

It's generally advised that you don't lock on `this`, since someone else might do so and ruin your day (especially given you `Deflator` constructor and `Go()` methods are public); better to create a dedicated private lock-object so there can be no interference and it's clearer what the lock's job is (`this` alone is brittle, changing meaning if moved to a method in a different class).

I think this code in `SaveMatch` can end up blocking longer than necessary when the buffer is filled... though it's probably never going to happen.

```
while ( i == BufferRead )
lock ( this )
{
  BufferFull = true;
  if ( InputWait ) Monitor.Pulse( this );
  Monitor.Wait( this );
  BufferFull = false;
}
```

Sequence:

1. On the match-finding thread (A) `BufferRead` is read such that it appears the buffer is full, then the thread is swapped out...
2. The other thread (B) then resets `BufferRead` to something else in `PutCodes`, and manages to get out of `OutputBlock` before being swapped out
3. The same thread (B) then checks `BufferFull` and finds it `false`. This thread is swapped out
4. Thread (A) now enters the while-loop (having already read `BufferRead`), takes the lock, sets `BufferFull = true`, pulses, and waits
5. Thread (B) in `WaitForInput` observes `BufferFull == true` and doesn't pulse the monitor again until it leaves `OutputBlock` - which might take a short while if decides to read a large dynamic block - during which time Thread (A) is stalled

Checking `BufferRead` inside the lock would prevent any such possibility by ensuring a fresh read before waiting.

If I'm understanding the checks against `BufferWrite` correctly, that first `MemoyBarrier` in `SaveMatch` has a somewhat unclear job in keeping `BufferWrite != BufferRead`. (It's probably redundant because of the lock, but I'd keep it for clarity and honour it with a comment explaining why it is necessary to defer assigning `BufferWrite` if it is)

## Boring Misc

- You might consider the generic overload of `QueueUserWorkItem`, just to remove the cast in `FindMatchesStart`.
- You are slightly inconsistent with your spacing before `(`, which makes it harder to quickly navigate the code (two instances of `lock(`). There are also a couple of lopsided things like `(uint)(length-MatchOff[ mc ] )`
- The `HuffmanCoding`s in `Block` are missing an access modifier; do they want to be `private readonly`? `BufferStart` and `BufferEnd` also look like they want to be `readonly` to go along with `Start` and `End`.

Comment: I don't think that thread (A) gets stalled for long, after PutCodes increments BufferRead, OutputBlock exits immediately ( it only outputs a single block once it has decided on the block size ), and then thread (A) gets the required Pulse from the while ( !OutputBlock() ) loop in Deflator.Go ?

On misc point (1) am not quite sure what you are referring to, it would be nice to get rid of the rather ugly "Object" method, but I don't know exactly how.

Other points I agree, thanks for the review.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood I could be barking up the wrong tree, but the idea is that if `BufferRead` is set and it (doesn't) Pulse in the while loop between `BufferRead` being read and `Wait` in `SaveMatch`, then it will 'miss' the Pulse and have to wait for `OutputBlock` to exit again; checking `BufferRead` again inside the lock in `SaveMatch` precludes this (no doubt very unlikely and probably not significant) possibility. Misc point (1), I mean something like `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem<Deflator>(FindMatchesStart, this, false );` with new signature `FindMatchesStart(Defalator d)`.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean now. I need to test for `i == BufferRead` again inside the lock as well.

On QueueUserWorkItem the generic version doesn't seem to be in my version on .Net, and I am not sure of it's official status.

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood ah, looks like it is exclusive to .NET Core.

Comment: I have now made a `matcher` struct which addresses the Code Separation it handles the matching and also all the threading logic. Revised code is at https://github.com/georgebarwood/pdf/blob/master/Deflator.cs

Comment: @GeorgeBarwood oh, that's much better that what I came up with... good idea putting `WaitForInput` in the struct; I was trying to keep that outside and kept getting myself in a tangle!

Answer (score 1):

In SaveMatch, I think that I need an extra `MemoryBarrier` in this code:

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
BufferWrite = i;
position += length;
Buffered = position;
```

If `BufferWrite = i` is re-ordered after `Buffered = position` the code doing the Huffman compression might not see the match ( or worse, might not see it when computing the codes, but see it when the block is written, and not have a code available to encode the match ). So I have changed this to:

```
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
BufferWrite = i;
position += length;
Thread.MemoryBarrier();
Buffered = position;
```